# How can I store a unique ID into mySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to store a unique ID into my SQL database. Therefore I am using `UUID()`.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id) VALUES (UUID());
```

As a result I get a string like this:

```
f4e871u6-7250-11e3-b5e4-de5d53a21b63
```

Is it possible to store this string without dashes and only 22 characters long?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Use replace like this

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, age) 
SELECT substr(replace(UUID(), '-', ''), 1, 22), ?, ?
```

or that

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, age) 
VALUES (substr(replace(UUID(), '-', ''), 1, 22), ?, ?)
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cbac/1)

But have a look on [how the UUID is built](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). You should better not take only a part of the UUID. It will not be so unique any more.

Comment: Thank you! So you mean first `INSERT` and then `SELECT id  FROM mytable REPLACE (UUID(), '-', '');`

Comment: Oh thank you, I will change `number` to `string` in my question

Comment: Thank you for the edit, so if I have more values to insert is this the right way to write it: `INSERT INTO my_table (id,name,age) VALUES (UUID(),?,?) SELECT replace(UUID(), '-', '');` or do I need two different inserts?

Comment: I also need the string to be only 22 characters long, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Now it is inserting always the same string! It is not unique anymore. What can I do?

Comment: I see. Working on it.